# The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, flask

i am having and issue here in my blog website....i want the user to be able to comment under a post but it kept showning me that,i don't know what else to do i have tried but it kept repeating this

here is my route

```
@posts.route("/create-comment/<post_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_comment(post_id):
    text = request.form.get['text']

    if not text:
        flash('Comment cannot be empty.', 'danger')
    else:
        post = Post.query.filter_by(post_id)
        if post:
            comment = Comment(text=text, post_id=post_id, author=current_user)
            db.session.add(comment)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            flash('Post not found.', 'danger')
    
    return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=post_id))
```

my model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    Comment = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    Comment = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text(200), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Comment('{self.content}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

my form

```
 <form class="input-group mb-3" method="POST" action="/create_comment">
        <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" name="comment">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Post</button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

guys please help me out

Comment: have you added your route to blueprints?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your html:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('create_comment', post_id=post.id) }}" method = "POST">
```

Comment: please still same error

Comment: try again, I edited the line of code

Answer (score 0):

Your action route in the form is wrong. It should be `/create_comment/<post_id>`.

Comment: he has to use the post id to first query the post and then add a comment to it

Comment: @SLDem, yeah, sorry, didn't notice at first. Since usually, those routes are written as `post_id/create_comment`. totally my bad.

Comment: am still getting same error

Comment: @cashie_tech can you please share the full `Traceback`? It'll be much easier to help with that information.

Comment: i can't add a comment or like to the blog website it kept on give me same issues